How to customize style of django-autocomplete-light Forms
I need your help on customizing the style of TextInput Box while using django-autocomplete-light.
Specifically, I have a data model TextHeader, UserInputDataSearch then I'm creating a view object as
# views.py
class DataSearchAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    model = UserInputDataSearch
    form_class = SearchDataForm
    success_url = 'data_access'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = TextHeader.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(keywordFinder__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs

The forms.py is as below
class SearchDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    userSearch = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=TextHeader.objects.all(),
        widget = autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='dataSearch-autocomplete',
            attrs={
                'data-html': True,
                "type":"search",
                "class":"form-control",
                "id":"autoCompleteData",
                "autocomplete":"off",
                },
        )
    )
    

    
    dateRange = fields.DateRangeField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
        widget=widgets.DateRangeWidget(
            format='%d/%m/%Y',           
        )
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserInputDataSearch
        fields = ["userSearch"]

Then, on html template, I write down these lines
#htmlTemplate
               <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row g-3">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div>
                                {{ form.userSearch|as_crispy_field }}  
                            </div> 
                        </div><!--end col-->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div>
                                {{ form.dateRange|as_crispy_field }}
        
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end col-->
                       
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="text-left">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Find</button>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end col-->
                    </div><!--end row-->
                </form> 

However, it renders my page with difference style of two boxes as a screenshot below, I wonder how to make them in the same style


I see you are using crispy forms and bootstrap. Have you installed the bootstrap template pack for crispy forms?

You could try using the boostrap-5 theme for select2. Described here: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/1318#issuecomment-1460127046
